# SH: how to convert the date "Nov 26 23:59:00 2022 GMT" to timestamp?

Tags: shell, timestamp

I want to convert the string "Nov 26 23:59:00 2022 GMT" to a timestamp 1669507140000. I checked the [man date](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) to get this command:

```
date  -d "Nov 26 23:59:00 2022 GMT" +"%s"
```

But his returns: 1669507140 (the last 3 zeros are missing).

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: Use `+%s000` then

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the **date** command that I have on my system (YMMV) will show us what it is doing if we add the `--debug` flag to our invocation...

```
$ date  -d "Nov 26 23:59:00 2022 GMT" +"%s" --debug
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2020-11-26
date: parsed time part: 23:59:00
date: parsed number part: year: 2022
date: parsed zone part: UTC+00
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (+00)
date: using specified time as starting value: '23:59:00'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2022-11-26 23:59:00 TZ=+00'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2022-11-26 23:59:00 TZ=+00' = 1669507140 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1669507140.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2022-11-26 23:59:00 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2022-11-27 07:59:00 (UTC+08)
1669507140
```

The debug log shows us the `%s` format will result in displaying seconds since epoch. Alternatively, nanosecond precision can be achieved using a modified format string (I added a `.001` in the date string to prove it works):

```
$ date -d "Nov 26 23:59:00.001 2022 GMT" +"%s.%N" --debug
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2020-11-26
date: parsed time part: 23:59:00
date: parsed number part: year: 2022
date: parsed zone part: UTC+00
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (+00)
date: using specified time as starting value: '23:59:00'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2022-11-26 23:59:00 TZ=+00'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2022-11-26 23:59:00 TZ=+00' = 1669507140 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1669507140.001000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2022-11-26 23:59:00 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2022-11-27 07:59:00 (UTC+08)
1669507140.001000000
```

We can use a pipe to **awk** to round up to milliseconds for our final form (note I used `.0005` in the date string here to show rounding):

```
$ date -d "Nov 26 23:59:00.0005 2022 GMT" +"%s.%N" | awk '{ printf("%d\n", int($0 * 1000) + (int($0 * 2000) % 2)) }'
1669507140001
```

One further note.... The following is the version of the **date** command I am using:

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

Comment: appearing a extra .000.... is not the same as missing 000 at the end. But i think your are right. It shows seconds and i need miliseconds so, it is jsut add the 3 zeros in the results (1s = 1000 ms).

Comment: @Kaspacainoombro -- note that the code above doesn't simply append 0's... It will instead accurately keep track of milliseconds if they are included in the input date string.

Comment: the miliseconds do not appear in the original string. But thank you

Comment: The answer will handle date strings either with or without sub-second information included.